# After session timeout redirect to last visited page for previous user

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, redirect, struts

When the session is timeout, I redirect to login page. I need that, whether the login user name is same user name, which was logged in before session timeout, then the page will be redirect to previous user visited page from login page.

For example,

```
        User name is Admin, when this user is open ContactUs.jsp, after the session timeout the page will be redirect to login.jsp, In login.jsp whether the same Admin user is logged in then, the page is redirect to ContactUs.jsp instead of home.jsp.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this is by using cookies.

But the best way is the below one.

If you are using a DB in you application then you can do it in the below way:

1. Create a table in your DB with fields `IP Address`, `User Name`, `Last Visited Page`.
2. When user performs `Login`, insert the values into your table.
3. When user performs `Logout` or when `Session time Out occurs`, update your table and set `Last Visited Page` to the current jsp name.
4. Again at `Login`,  before inserting a row in your table, make a check on `IP Address`. If a row is present with the current `IP Address` and if `User Names` match, then retrieve the `Last Visited Page` value from the table and forward the user to that JSP Page.

Comment: Whether the user visit the page contains post method means, the parameter value is not get from the server right. Then how can we store the values in DB details.?